# What is the difference between using range in the first program and not using it in the second program?

Tags: python

For an assignment, I needed to make a program that counts the vowels and consonants in a string using `for i in range(0, len(str)):`

I put this program together using what I learned, but I can't really wrap my head around why it works.

```
vowelCount = 0
consonantCount = 0

sentence = input("Enter your sentence: ")

for char in range(0, len(sentence)):
    if sentence[char] in "aeiouAEIOU":
        vowelCount += 1
    if sentence[char] in "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ":
        consonantCount += 1

print("There are", vowelCount, "vowels")
print("There are", consonantCount, "consonants")
```

Why am I getting the range of the length of the sentence?

Here's an alternative program I wrote without the range.

```
vowelCount = 0
consonantCount = 0

sentence = input("Enter your sentence: ")

for i in sentence: 
    if i in "aeiouAEIOU":
        vowelCount += 1
    if i in "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ":
        consonantCount += 1

print("There are", vowelCount, "vowels")
print("There are", consonantCount, "consonants")
```

Why do I need to use sentence[char] in the range version? Why the brackets?

Comment: Instead of `"a"` you have `sentence[char]` (which is one letter out of `sentence`) and instead of `apple` you have `"aeiouAEIOU"`. Is it now clear?

Comment: The lines you were asking about do not *find* the vowels. They test *if* something is a vowel (or a consonant).

Comment: Part of the confusion might be that `char` is not a character (i.e. a string of length 1), but an integer. You could try `print(char)` and `print(sentence[char])` each loop if that would help you understand. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: BTW, you could simplify by using all lowercase: `if sentence[char].lower() in "aeiou"`.

Comment: Please change the title to reflect your changed question -- maybe something like "Why do I need to use the range of the length to loop over a string?"

Comment: Here's the relevant section in the official tutorial: [The `range()` Function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function), under "To iterate over the indices of a sequence ...". And a relevant existing question: [Accessing the index in 'for' loops](/q/522563/4518341), especially [this answer](/a/28072982/4518341).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is going through `sentence` one letter at a time. For each letter (retreived by `sentence[char]`) it checks whether it is in the list of vowels (if yes, increment `vowelCount`) or in the list of consonants (if yes, increment `consonantCount`).

The form `a in b` for strings a and b checks whether a is contained somewhere as exact substring in `b`. So if `a` is just a single letter, it checks whether `b` contains the letter `a` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect part of your confusion might arise because of the word "char." In the following code snippet, `range(0, len(sentence))` generates numerical values. Thus, char is an **index**.

```
for char in range(0, len(sentence))
```

In other words, on the first iteration through the loop `sentence[char]` really looks something like `sentence[0]`, or the first character in the sentence. If this character is in the string "aeiouAEIOU", the the boolean conditional in the loop returns `TRUE`

Note that `if sentence[char] in "aeiouAEIOU"` could be re-written like

```
if sentence[char] in set(['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U'])
```

Comment: Why `set([...])` instead of a set literal `{...}`?

Answer (score -1):

**First:** `"aeiouAEIOU"` is a string, which can also be seen as a List of characters in this context.

So `['a', 'e', 'i', 'o'....'U']` is equivalent to this string representation above.

**Second**: The `in` operator in python checks if the element on the left side is "in" the list on the right side. So for example
`1 in [1,2,3]` would return `TRUE` while `10 in [1,2,3]` would return `FALSE`. Or for characters, `'o' in "Foobar"` would return `TRUE` while `'c' in "Foobar"` would return `FALSE`

The rest is just `(pseudocode) IF ... THEN increase a number`, so you basically loop through every character of a sentence and increase two variables if the character is in the list of vovels or in the list of consonants. After the loop is finished, you present the final counts.

Comment: *"a string, which is a fancy name for just a List of characters"* -- That's not really a useful way of thinking about it in a Python context, cause lists are mutable while strings aren't. Plus lists are containers while strings aren't. And strings have a ton of unique methods like `.upper()`.

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks, you are surely right on this point. I changed the sentence to better reflect what I meant in this context.